# How to create a job on google big query to extract data from R

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, chrome-ux-report

```
> sql <- "SELECT * FROM `chrome-ux-report:all.201806` WHERE origin like `*****`"

> project <-"chrome-ux-report"

> data_201806 <- query_exec(sql, project = project, useLegacySql = FALSE)
```

Error: Access Denied: Project chrome-ux-report: The user *********.com does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project chrome-ux-report. [accessDenied]

have replaced some information with *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot run query in public project! Public project allows you to read data but not write or run jobs (query) in it
Instead you need to use your own project which has billing enabled or any project where you have bigquery.jobs.create premissions and run your query in it!
That way you'll run queries/jobs in your project where you have permissions to do so.